# FTP Server - 553 Could not create file

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

Hi iam trying to upload a file to an **Linux FTP** server using **vsftpd**

When uploading a file (eather through FileZilla or via batch script) i recieve the error 553

My vsftpd.conf looks as followed:

```
# Example config file /etc/vsftpd.conf
#
# The default compiled in settings are fairly paranoid. This sample file
# loosens things up a bit, to make the ftp daemon more usable.
# Please see vsftpd.conf.5 for all compiled in defaults.
#
# READ THIS: This example file is NOT an exhaustive list of vsftpd options.
# Please read the vsftpd.conf.5 manual page to get a full idea of vsftpd's
# capabilities.
#
#
# Run standalone?  vsftpd can run either from an inetd or as a standalone
# daemon started from an initscript.
listen=NO
#
# This directive enables listening on IPv6 sockets. By default, listening
# on the IPv6 "any" address (::) will accept connections from both IPv6
# and IPv4 clients. It is not necessary to listen on *both* IPv4 and IPv6
# sockets. If you want that (perhaps because you want to listen on specific
# addresses) then you must run two copies of vsftpd with two configuration
# files.
listen_ipv6=YES
#
# Allow anonymous FTP? (Disabled by default).
anonymous_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this to allow local users to log in.
local_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this to enable any form of FTP write command.
write_enable=YES
#
# Default umask for local users is 077. You may wish to change this to 022,
# if your users expect that (022 is used by most other ftpd's)
#local_umask=022
#
# Uncomment this to allow the anonymous FTP user to upload files. This only
# has an effect if the above global write enable is activated. Also, you will
# obviously need to create a directory writable by the FTP user.
anon_upload_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this if you want the anonymous FTP user to be able to create
# new directories.
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
#
# Activate directory messages - messages given to remote users when they
# go into a certain directory.
dirmessage_enable=YES
#
# If enabled, vsftpd will display directory listings with the time
# in  your  local  time  zone.  The default is to display GMT. The
# times returned by the MDTM FTP command are also affected by this
# option.
use_localtime=YES
#
# Activate logging of uploads/downloads.
xferlog_enable=YES
#
# Make sure PORT transfer connections originate from port 20 (ftp-data).
connect_from_port_20=YES
#
# If you want, you can arrange for uploaded anonymous files to be owned by
# a different user. Note! Using "root" for uploaded files is not
# recommended!
chown_uploads=YES
chown_username=sven
#
# You may override where the log file goes if you like. The default is shown
# below.
#xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
#
# If you want, you can have your log file in standard ftpd xferlog format.
# Note that the default log file location is /var/log/xferlog in this case.
#xferlog_std_format=YES
#
# You may change the default value for timing out an idle session.
#idle_session_timeout=600
#
# You may change the default value for timing out a data connection.
#data_connection_timeout=120
#
# It is recommended that you define on your system a unique user which the
# ftp server can use as a totally isolated and unprivileged user.
#nopriv_user=ftpsecure
#
# Enable this and the server will recognise asynchronous ABOR requests. Not
# recommended for security (the code is non-trivial). Not enabling it,
# however, may confuse older FTP clients.
#async_abor_enable=YES
#
# By default the server will pretend to allow ASCII mode but in fact ignore
# the request. Turn on the below options to have the server actually do ASCII
# mangling on files when in ASCII mode.
# Beware that on some FTP servers, ASCII support allows a denial of service
# attack (DoS) via the command "SIZE /big/file" in ASCII mode. vsftpd
# predicted this attack and has always been safe, reporting the size of the
# raw file.
# ASCII mangling is a horrible feature of the protocol.
#ascii_upload_enable=YES
#ascii_download_enable=YES
#
# You may fully customise the login banner string:
#ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.
#
# You may specify a file of disallowed anonymous e-mail addresses. Apparently
# useful for combatting certain DoS attacks.
#deny_email_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#banned_email_file=/etc/vsftpd.banned_emails
#
# You may restrict local users to their home directories.  See the FAQ for
# the possible risks in this before using chroot_local_user or
# chroot_list_enable below.
chroot_local_user=YES
#
# You may specify an explicit list of local users to chroot() to their home
# directory. If chroot_local_user is YES, then this list becomes a list of
# users to NOT chroot().
# (Warning! chroot'ing can be very dangerous. If using chroot, make sure that
# the user does not have write access to the top level directory within the
# chroot)
#chroot_local_user=YES
#chroot_list_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
#
# You may activate the "-R" option to the builtin ls. This is disabled by
# default to avoid remote users being able to cause excessive I/O on large
# sites. However, some broken FTP clients such as "ncftp" and "mirror" assume
# the presence of the "-R" option, so there is a strong case for enabling it.
#ls_recurse_enable=YES
#
# Customization
#
# Some of vsftpd's settings don't fit the filesystem layout by
# default.
#
# This option should be the name of a directory which is empty.  Also, the
# directory should not be writable by the ftp user. This directory is used
# as a secure chroot() jail at times vsftpd does not require filesystem
# access.
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
#
# This string is the name of the PAM service vsftpd will use.
pam_service_name=ftp
#
# This option specifies the location of the RSA certificate to use for SSL
# encrypted connections.
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
ssl_enable=NO
pasv_enable=YES
port_enable=YES
port_promiscuous=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
#
# Uncomment this to indicate that vsftpd use a utf8 filesystem.
utf8_filesystem=YES
local_root=/
```

Ps.: I know i should not use the root folder as dropoff, this will be changed to a apache2 webserver later on

My question is, if anyone has experience with this error and has an idea on how to solve it. Iam not deeply familiar with linux so i would be happy if you asnwers can be "dumbed down" as far as possible.

The batch script for upload is:

```
@echo off

echo user anonymous> ftpcmd.dat
echo >> ftpcmd.dat
echo put C:\Users\Anwender\Downloads\%1 %1>> ftpcmd.dat
REM echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -d -s:ftpcmd.dat 194.26.183.194
del ftpcmd.dat
```

With the output:

```
Verbindung mit 194.26.183.194 wurde hergestellt.
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)
---> OPTS UTF8 ON
200 Always in UTF8 mode.
ftp> user anonymous
---> USER anonymous
331 Please specify the password.

---> PASS ECHO ist ausgeschaltet (OFF).
230 Login successful.
ftp> put C:\Users\Anwender\Downloads\Anwender_DESKTOP-V30SJ8P_2021-09-08-12-43-42.wav Anwender_DESKTOP-V30SJ8P_2021-09-08-12-43-42.wav
---> PORT 192,168,10,50,223,189
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
---> STOR Anwender_DESKTOP-V30SJ8P_2021-09-08-12-43-42.wav
553 Could not create file.
ftp>
```

While iam thankfull if someone can tell me how to fix it, i would prefere if you can also explain where and why it went wrong

Thanks you so much in advance

Answer (score 3):

I know OP has likely moved on by now, but for others viewing this page here is the likely issue.

- OP logs in as anonymous, so all write operations will be done with
  the 'other' permission group in user/group/other unix style.
- OP sets the chown_username as sven, so sven would own all the files and folders
- OP doesn't set the ftp server user, so the ftp server interacts with the files using 'other' permissions. This is a problem as 'other' usually cannot write files into folders.
- OP doesn't change the umask, so all files uploaded / folders created will not allow writing by 'other'

We will fix all of these in short order. However we need some background in how permissions work on a Linux system.

## Linux Permissions

You will see permissions presented as three numbers, usually 755 or 644. Each number corresponds to a different permissions scope. The scopes are user-group-other. User means the permissions for the owner of the file. Group means the permissions for anyone that shares a group with the group owner of the file. This is useful for shared folders like ftp, where ftp might own all the files, but other users can gain access by adding the ftp group permissions to their account. The last scope is 'other'. Other means the permissions applied to all other users except the owner.

Next, what do the numbers for each scope mean? Why 7 vs 6 or 5? These numbers correspond to read-write-execute permissions. These permissions are a binary representation, so '7' is 0b111, 6 is 0b110... 2 is 0b010, 1 is 0b001. A 1 means the permission is allowed and 0 disallowed. For example, take 7=0b111. This is saying that read, write, and execute is allowed. Another example of 6=0b110 means read and write are allowed while execute is disallowed.

The last thing to keep in mind is the difference between normal permissions and umask permissions. Umasks are used to determine permissions when creating a new file. Normal permissions are what I've been describing. Umask permissions operate mostly the same, except they flip the rule that 0 means disallowed and 1 allowed. So in umask land, 000 actually means read-write-execute are allowed for all user-group-other. The more common 022 umask simply disallows writing for group and other. This would be good if you want to share files with other users but don't want them to be able to change your files.

So keeping that in mind, we have to configure the ftp server so that the ftp server itself and anonymous users are able to read files and write new files inside directories. So a proper setup would include this:

### vsftpd.conf

```
chown_username=ftp
ftp_username=ftp        # the server will read files/folders as the same user that it chowns files to
local_umask=022         # umask to remove write permissions from group/other
anon_umask=022          # same umask for anon uploads
```

Create ftp user and ensure the files/folders in the ftp folder have the correct permissions

```
useradd ftp -p ftp-password                           # choose an appropriate ftp password
chown ftp:ftp /path/to/ftp -R                         # recursively change ownership of all files/folders to ftp
find /path/to/ftp/ -type d -exec chmod 755 \{\} \;    # this loops over all directories and gives user=rwx, group=rx, other=rx permissions
find /path/to/ftp/ -type f -exec chmod 644 \{\} \;    # this loops over all files and gives user=rw, group=r, other=r permissions
```